# Running tata photon max on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount

I am not able to install tata photon max on my ubuntu machine. My ubuntu is not able to auto mount the device so i first mount it manually by using this command `mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr1 /media/photon` . After that I try to install it as given with the guide `sh ./install_linux` but it is not installing and no window is appearing.

Please help how to run my tata photon max on ubuntu 14.04